# Nodejs stream with braintree?

Tags: node.js, stream, braintree

I am trying to build an api route for a transaction, I want to grab the transaction details from the braintree server.

My app is setup so that the braintree `customerId()` is the same as the ID as my app user. So below I search for all the transactions for a particular user logged in.

Meaning `req.user.id` will always equal `customerId()` which sits on the braintree server.

```
app.get('/project', function(req, res) {
  if(req.user) {

      // Finds all transactions for a particular customer
      var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
        search.customerId().is(req.user.id);
      });

      console.log(stream);
      //res.send(stream);
  }
});
```

I want to return the details, but the stream looks like below. So obviously this makes me think that there is a certain way to handle a node stream?

I have seen things like `readable-stream`, I am not sure if that is what I need to handle this stream object.

My question is how do I handle the stream object to return the details of the transaction?

```
{ _readableState:
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: true,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  searchResponse: { stream: [Circular], success: true },
  currentItem: 0,
  currentOffset: 0,
  bufferedResults: [] }
```

Answer (score 1):

This returned the transaction data. I am going to keep looking into node streams, and am open to making this better, but as of now it at least returns the data.

```
stream.on("data", function (data) {
  res.json(data);
});
```

This gives me an error though `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Answer (score 0):

I think stream.pipe(res) should work.

The reason you were getting that "can't set headers after they are sent" error, is because the streams 'data' event was emitted multiple times, so you were trying to call res.json multiple times for the same request.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out later on, but I was a little lost on how I could get the data objects out of the stream event. Just some basic vanilla JS that I totally did not think of using. ex. var objects = [], then in the stream data event push the objects into the objects array, then send to client on end.

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this library: https://github.com/rvagg/through2 - it is very convenient for stream manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the share, I have not come across that library looks super easy to use, and I might grab it.